# catch all file extension controller action together with static files

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a set of files in the wwwroot folder. With webpack I generate js bundles with js.map files. I want to put security on the *.map files to only allow certain people to have access to it.

The [documentation of ASP.NET core static files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files#static-file-authorization) concludes that all files in wwwroot have no security. If security is needed advice is given to make an MVC controller and to put security on the action method.

I want to have the static files in wwwroot with one catch all *.js.map URLs which performs security and gives a notfound. How do I define this action method.

I don't want to put the map files in a different folder and to serve them differently.

Comment: If I apply following I'm already closer but I can not map files in sub folders: [Route("{url:regex((.*?).map.js)}")]

Answer (score 0):

Define a route like this with a catchAll template and a constraint:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            // https://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx/
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "MapFiles", 
                template: "{*relativeFileUrl}", 
                defaults: new { controller = "FileSystem", action = "AccessDevFile" }, 
                constraints: new { relativeFileUrl = @".*\.js.map" }
            );
        });
```

The action method looks like this. If no access allowed we just return NotFound()

```
    public IActionResult AccessDevFile(string relativeFileUrl)
    {
        bool hasAccess = ... do your check ...
        if(hasAccess)
        {
            return base.PhysicalFile(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath + "\\" + relativeFileUrl.Replace("/", @"\"), "application/json");
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Also make sure to have the UseMvc call before the UserStaticFiles call otherwise the action method can never be reached.